# How to get the HttpContext in a razor component without inheriting from PageModel

Tags: dependency-injection, blazor, pipeline, blazor-server-side

I have an issue replacing the deprecated Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http library in my Blazor Server web app, and was looking for a way to get the IHttpContextAccessor.

The way I have it now is I've created a **BasePage** class which inherits from **ComponentBase**:

```
public class BasePage : ComponentBase
{
    [Inject] IJSRuntime JsRuntime { get; set; }
    [Inject] IHttpContextAccessor HttpAccessor { get; set; }

    //The rest of the code is omitted for brevity
}
```

This **BasePage** inheritance is used in all of my app's pages.

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-7.0#access-httpcontext-from-razor-pages) one way to do it is to inherit from PageModel. Unfortunately, this doesn't help me since I'm already using the **BaseComponent** inheritance.

Is there any other solution to get it?

Comment: Don't understand why and which library has it but, removing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http nuget package doesn't trigger any errors and the  IHttpContextAccessor is still recognised as derived from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http package. Hope this helps someone else...

Comment: PageModel is from Razor Pages, not Blazor.

Comment: Do not try to use in in a .razor component or page. You can access it [at startup in the Host.cshtml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/server/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-7.0#pass-tokens-to-a-server-side-blazor-app)

Comment: @HH True, thanks for pointing it. I've read this recently, a bit too late :) . Will have to refactor it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following the above advise and refactored my code using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/server/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-7.0#circuit-handler-to-capture-users-for-custom-services) reference. Here are the steps:

1. Created the UserService:

   ```
    public class UserService 
    {
         private ClaimsPrincipal currentUser = new(new ClaimsIdentity());

         public ClaimsPrincipal GetUser()
         {
              return currentUser;
         }

         internal void SetUser(ClaimsPrincipal user)
         {
              if (currentUser != user)
                  currentUser = user;            
         }
    }

    internal sealed class UserCircuitHandler : CircuitHandler, IDisposable
    {
         private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider;

         private readonly UserService userService;

         public UserCircuitHandler(AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider, UserService userService)
         {
              this.authenticationStateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;
              this.userService = userService;
         }

         public override Task OnCircuitOpenedAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         {                  
              authenticationStateProvider.AuthenticationStateChanged += AuthenticationChanged;
              return base.OnCircuitOpenedAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
         }

         private void AuthenticationChanged(Task<AuthenticationState> task)
         {
             _ = UpdateAuthentication(task);

             async Task UpdateAuthentication(Task<AuthenticationState> task)
             {
                 try
                 {
                     var state = await task;
                     userService.SetUser(state.User);
                 }
                 catch
                 {
                 }
             }
         }

         public override async Task OnConnectionUpAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         {  
             var state = await authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();

             userService.SetUser(state.User);
         }

         public void Dispose()
         {
             authenticationStateProvider.AuthenticationStateChanged    -=  AuthenticationChanged;
         }
    }
   ```
2. Register the UserService in your pipeline in the Program.cs:

   ```
    builder.Services.AddScoped<UserService>();

    builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(
         ServiceDescriptor.Scoped<CircuitHandler, UserCircuitHandler>());
   ```

That's about it! you can get the Identity info by injecting your UserService in your pages, like so:

```
@inject UserService UserService

<h1>Hello, @(UserService.GetUser().Identity?.Name ?? "world")!</h1>
```

Or, like in my case, since I was doing it in my `BasePage` class, you can do it this way:

```
public class BasePage : ComponentBase
{
    [Inject] IJSRuntime JsRuntime { get; set; }
    [Inject] UserService UsrService { get; set; }

    //The rest of the code is omitted for brevity
}
```

Hope it helps someone out there.